# Crashes without any error in logcat, while checking permission

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I want to check the permission for the location but during execution, the app crashes without showing any error. So that the line which causes the error is not showing. Please suggest me an edit, or solution for this issue.
I wrote this code in a fragment.

Thanks in advance.

> **function which checks permission**

```
String[] permissionsRequired = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};


private void checkPermission() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permissionsRequired[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), permissionsRequired[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permissionsRequired[0])
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), permissionsRequired[1])) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissionsRequired, PERMISSION_CALLBACK_CONSTANT);
        }


    } else {

    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure you have added those permission in manifest?

Comment: @KaranMer yes sir

Comment: can you post error log? make sure you have not provided any unnecessary filters in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    checkPermissions();
}



 private void checkPermissions(){
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }else{
        getMyLocation();
    }

}





private void getMyLocation(){
    if(googleApiClient!=null) {
        Log.e("TAg", "getMyLocation: " + "goolenot null" );
        if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.e("TAG", "getMyLocation: " + "connectd" );
            int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
                builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
            //    map_view.getMapAsync(this);
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                        .requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
                PendingResult result =
                        LocationServices.SettingsApi
                                .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback() {

                                             @Override
                                             public void onResult(@NonNull Result result) {
                                                 final Status status = result.getStatus();
                                                 switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                                                     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                                         // All location settings are satisfied.
                                                         // You can initialize location requests here.
                                                         int permissionLocation = ContextCompat
                                                                 .checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                                                         Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
                                                         if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                                         //    lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                                                          //           .getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                                                             setFragmentoriginal(new HomeFragment());
                                                             changePositiono(0);
                                                         }
                                                         break;
                                                     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                                         // Location settings are not satisfied.
                                                         // But could be fixed by showing the user a dialog.
                                                         try {
                                                             // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                                             // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                                             // Ask to turn on GPS automatically
                                                             status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                                                     REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS);
                                                         } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                                             // Ignore the error.
                                                         }
                                                         break;
                                                     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                                         // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                                                         // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                                                         //finish();
                                                         break;
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }

                );
            }
        }
    }
}





  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    int permissionLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (permissionLocation == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getMyLocation();
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    getMyLocation();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}





private final static int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS_GPS = 0x1;
private final static int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 0x2;
```

enjoy

Comment: let me check it sir

Comment: if your problem is solved you must checked this as answer